# The following ODE global existence theorem reference?

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

There is an ODE existence theorem of the form:

> Let $f:[a,b]\times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a Caratheodory function.
>
> Suppose that there is a constant $c$ such that if $y$ is a solution, then $|y(t)| \leq c$ on any subinterval of $[a,b]$.
>
> Furthermore, if $|v| \leq C$, there is a $h_C \in L^1$ such that $|f(t,v)| \leq h_C(t)$.
>
> Then the ODE $y'(t) = f(t,y(t))$ with $y(0)=y_0$ has a global solution on $[a,b]$ (solution here means the equation holds pointwise a.e.).

Does anyone know of a reference for this statment (apart from Zeidler)? I am particularly needing the condition about $h_C$ with the integrability bound only on a ball of radius $C$.

C/p from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1326339/the-following-ode-global-existence-theorem-reference.

Comment: I don't understand the second condition. What if we take an initial value $>c$?

Comment: @ChristianRemling I think we consider the initial value to be fixed. Then $c$ is chosen always bigger than $y_0$.